# rails cannot find installed gem in rvm configuration

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I split my development between two machines with a Bitbucket-hosted git repo to make sure they're in sync:

- Linux Mint
- Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

I've got my `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock`, `.ruby-version`, and `.ruby-gemset` set up to peg both environments to the same configuration (ruby 2.4.0 and a gemset called `cs2`).

I've added the following to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'google_drive'
```

and `bundle install` runs successfully:

```
...
Using google_drive 2.1.5
...
```

On the Win 10 machine, I can then run `rails c` to get to the console, but on the Linux Mint machine I'm met with:

```
Could not find google_drive-2.1.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Clearly I have a misconfiguration somewhere on my Linux Mint machine, but I'm not sure how to find the problem. It only seems to be the one gem, too. I tried to empty the gemset and rebuild it and I see the same problem. I tried deleting the gemset and, again, I see the same thing. Any ideas? I tried running `gem install google_drive --version 2.1.5` and still no luck.

What else can I try? Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

please run 'rvm current' to check your current gemset is cs2 on linux and delete the Gemfile.lock and rerun bundle install

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It gives me `ruby-2.4.0@cs2` -- which is what I expected, no?

Comment: yes, that's great, did you try deleting Gemfile.lock? and run bundle, also check your gem version by running 'gem -v'  as it worked for me with gem version 2.5.1

Comment: That did not help things, but after making some changes, it now seems to complain of being unable to find a different gem. Some commands seem to work and others seem to give me this sort of error.